# Minimum value of the given function-

Tags: functions, contest-math

Find the minimum value of-
$$\frac{(x+\frac{1}{x})^6-(x^6+\frac{1}{x^6})-2}{(x+\frac{1}{x})^3+(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3})}$$
I tried opening the brackets and trying to cancel the terms and using AM-GM.

Comment: Have you tried calculating it's derivative using the chain rule?

Comment: That's not a polynomial.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson Can you please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @PiyushJoshi it only has a minimum over $\mathbb{R}^+$... and a maximum over $\mathbb{R}^-$. Considering the first option, the minimum is attained at $x=1$ and is equal to $6$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint.

Calling

$$
u = x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\\
v = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3
$$

we have

$$
\frac{v^2-u^2}{v+u}=v-u = 3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ge 6
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $z=x+\frac1x$. Then the function is equal to
$$\frac{z^6-(z^6-6z^4+9z^2-2)-2}{z^3+z^3-3z}=\frac{6z^4-9z^2}{2z^3-3z}=\frac{3z^2(2z^2-3)}{z(2z^2-3)}$$
Now $z$ can never assume a value in $(-2,2)$ and $2z^2-3=0\implies z=\sqrt{3/2}\in(-2,2)$, so we can cancel and get $3z$. Since $z$ has no minimum over the reals, so does the original function, but over the positive reals it does have a minimum of $6$.

Comment: when $x=1$ $(z=2)$